# psutil AttributeError: 'ModuleWrapper' object has no attribute 'NoSuchprocess'

Tags: python-2.7, psutil

```
for myprocess in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        myexe = myprocess.cmdline()
    except psutil.NoSuchprocess:
    myexe = None
```

**This show an error**

```
AttributeError: 'ModuleWrapper' object has no attribute 'NoSuchprocess'
```

Comment: If you provide more details like your import lines and if you correct your indentation it will be more easy to help you out.

Comment: Sorry , I removed the import lines as none of them except psutil matter and the error is specific to psutil